# Crystal reports not working with schema for stored procedure using csharp

Tags: crystal-reports, report

Schema with stored procedure getting blank crystal report.
For example Procedure Name is Certification.Fetch_TAUSMCAHdr but from csharp code schema is not binding as shown below.
Schema not binding

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow ! You should add more details such as sample of your code and your execution log as it will help us help you. You can also take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), it will help you understand how to properly ask a question :)